# Resize an Image file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, resize

I'm writing an iPhone app.
I want a UIImagePicker control to come up when the app is launched. When the user selects an image, I want to resize that to being 512x512 with the original image just in the top-left. I then want to save it to a new file in my app's folder.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I downvoted this question because this forum is for technical questions. Not for 'please write my code'. Why don't you make a start with this code and if you run into problems, ask a more specific question here.

Comment: @St3fn You know, when you hit 3k rep you can start closing bad questions too :)

Comment: Working on it :-) But I like to encourage people to write code first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you add a view to one of the default iPhone templates of your choosing. Then add a UIImagePicker to that view. Use one of the UIImagePicker delegates to resize the image and save to the file system. Then dismiss the UIIPickerView and load a new view with the new picture, and the original UIIPickerImage in the top left.

That's how you do it, and that answers your question.